# I cant get form value with isset($_POST['id');

Tags: php, forms, post, isset

I can't get the 'etkinlik_id' value from my form with if(isset($_POST[]))

I ve a button in form and I want it to send event_id to the query but when I'm trying this there is no data displaying

FORM codes are here ;

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="etkinlik_id" value="<?php echo $row['etkinlik_id']; ?>">
  <button type="submit" name="etkinlikdetayi" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#etkinlikx">ETKINLIK GOSTER</button>
</form>
```

PHP QUERY IS HERE;

```php
  if(isset($_POST['etkinlikdetayi'])){
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM etkinlikler WHERE etkinlik_id=:etkinlik_id');
    $query->execute(array(
      'etkinlik_id' => $_POST['etkinlik_id']
    ));
    $row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
```

Thanks for help and advices...

Comment: 1) Fix the input tag syntax - closing the tag is important. 2) If the form code and php code are not in the same file, you need to specify the php filename in action attribute of form tag. 3) The form code has php code in it, please check if that is being loaded in HTML by using View Source/Inspect element. 4) Use print_r($_POST); exit(); on top of the php file to see if there is any post values after form submission. Hope this helps you to debug and fix the issue.

Comment: @KiranD they don't necessarily have to be in the same file. The form target could include the PHP script, for example. I'd say the unclosed `<input>` tag is the real problem here.

Comment: @Phil Please read my second point in the first comment. I didn't say they should exist in the same file.

Comment: @KiranD what I meant is OP can keep using `action=""` and say that action resolves to `fileA.php`, the PHP code above doesn't need to be in `fileA.php` if it includes `fileB.php` which does contain that code.

Comment: @Phil Gotcha!! .. Agree with you mate..

Comment: So now that you've fixed the typo, what happens? Check your browser's _Network_ console and inspect the _"Form Data"_ for the request when you submit the form. Does it include both `etkinlik_id` and `etkinlikdetayi` parameters? You say there is _"no data displaying"_ but your PHP code does not **display** anything. How are you verifying this is an actual problem?

Comment: I ve more code which is fetching data with echo but i shared the important part because echo is a baby toy you know  i didnt copy paste i wrote the code here again but i missed closing tag of input. In original code there is really a closing tag... and all codes are in same file.

Comment: I think the problem is about the submit button. Because when i am trying to post it works to open modal. I checked the chrome dev tools screen and i cant see any post action.

Answer (score 0):

The two code snippets must in the same file, if they aren't in the same file you will have to specify the file path of the other PHP file to the action attribute of your form element.

Also your input is not closed.